# C# Access variables of different threads from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

So there's the situation - When the console application starts, it creates 3 threads that stay there forever and do whatever they are supposed to do. Any of those threads will then be able to show up a windows form as a separate thread so it doesn't wait for it to return anything using this code:

```
public void RunThread()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunForm));
    thread.Name = "StatusForm";
    thread.Start();
}

public void RunForm()
{
    Application.Run(new StatusForm());
}
```

This windows form will then attempt to get some variables from all 3 threads, I do that using:

```
int var1 = Manager1.InventoryEntriesOne
int var2 = Manager2.InventoryEntriesTwo
int var3 = Manager3.InventoryEntriesThree
```

The InventoryEntries in the first thread is declared like this (Same goes for other 2 threads):

```
public static volatile InventoryEntries
```

Now for some reason what happens is the windows form only shows the variables of the thread that has brought up the window using the `RunThread()` function. For example if Thread 1 starts the window, only the variables of that thread will be shown up, for Thread 2 and 3 it will be all 0. It needs to be able to read variables from all 3 threads, doesn't matter which thread launched the window.

Thank you.

**-----------------EDIT-------------------**

Let me just show you a brief example of what is happening inside of the code. This is example of Manager1, assume that 2 other managers are doing basically the same thing...

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Manager
{
    public class Manager1 : Manager
    {
        public static volatile int InventoryEntriesOne = 123;


        public override bool OnSomeEvent()
        {
            InventoryEntriesOne = 555;
        }

        public override bool OnSomeOtherEvent()
        {
            RunThread();
        }

        public void RunThread()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunForm));
            thread.Name = "StatusForm";
            thread.Start();
        }
        public void RunForm()
        {
            Application.Run(new StatusForm());
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the Manager is opening a windows form, now what happens in that form is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Manager
{
    public partial class StatusForm : Form
    {
        Timer refreshTimer = new Timer();

        public StatusForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PlotData();

            refreshTimer.Interval = 5000;  //5 seconds in milliseconds  
            refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshTimer_Tick);
            refreshTimer.Start();
        }

        void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlotData();
        }

        public void PlotData()
        {
            label1.Text = Manager1.InventoryEntriesOne.ToString();

            label2.Text = Manager2.InventoryEntriesTwo.ToString();

            label3.Text = Manager3.InventoryEntriesThree.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys will understand the problem now.

Comment: FYI: threads do not have parent-child relationships....

Comment: Sorry I'm new to programming and I just didn't know how to say it otherwise, you know what I mean, parent and child as in the "parent" thread creating the "child" thread if that even matters. I tried many solutions but I fail all the time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the definition of how the form gets access to the manager variables.

Comment: I just do it like this in the form: Manager1.InventoryEntriesOne

Comment: We need the code of Manager1/2/3

Comment: @RyanAmies First of all we need to know what OP asks for

Comment: There, I added the codes and edited the title a bit. Hopefully someone will be able to help me.

Comment: I think we have a more fundamental problem here. I can't imagine why you'd want to start a new thread for each form when you can just create three non-modal forms and show them. In any case, you haven't shown enough code to give us a clear idea of the problem.

Comment: Because all the forms are the same and they display info about all 3 managers, it doesn't matter which manager thread will show the form, it will still show info for all of the managers. The window is supposed to be open all the time, showing the status of variables inside all managers. When I firstly ran the form unthreaded, the execution of main application would be halted until I closed the form, therefore I had to thread it.

Comment: So, are you saying the console app starts Manager1, Manager2, and Manager3, each of which open a form; and the form corresponding to Manager 1 shows "555", "123", "123"; while form for Manager 2 shows "123", "555", "123"; and finally, form for Manager 3 shows "123", "123", "555"?  (Effectively, showing starting value for other managers, and the updated value for the manager owning the form.)

Comment: Console app starts Manager1, Manager2 and Manager3 threads. No forms are shown unless user wants to. At least one of the managers must be able to open the form, and the form must be able to display variables from all of the 3 managers. The numbers are irrelevant really. The form is supposed to say 123, 123, 123 at first unless a variable in one of the managers got updated. But instead if I launch the form from ex. Manager 1, the form will say 123, 0, 0.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem a bit. After initially declaring the variable in Manager, it gets set by default to 0. After reading the variable by the windows form thread, it still will be 0 no matter if I change the variable later in the Manager. If I declare it initially as for example value 50, the form will read it as 50. If I try to change it inside the Manager to lets say 10, the form thread will still see it as 50 no matter what I do with the variable. For some reason it only reads the first state of it, any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define InventoryEntries on Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

Try a different organization for your solution:

1. Have only 1 UI thread, managing all forms/windows and interactions with the user.
2. Have the UI thread above (create as necessary and) delegate work to background threads.
3. If thread start-up is **really** a measurable performance issue (I don't buy this *a priori* but it can happen) then have each instance of a Manager form cache a reference to it's private background thread.
4. When the background threads complete work, and need to update their assigned Manager form, have them use **Invoke()**.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm trying to do. The main thread is a console application. It doesn't matter if the rest of the managers are able to display the form. At least Manager1 must be able to do it since the form will show status of all the managers anyway so the forms are not assigned in any way, the form is universal for all of the managers. I need to be able to pull the variables out of the Managers by the form itself, from what I see the Invoke() function works the other way around. Also the only UI thread that I got there is the status form itself. The rest is in the main console app.

Comment: re "The main thread is a console application" Why? What business requirement necessitates this solution architecture? As for the rest, sentences of multiple clauses are often inappropriate for requirements specification, as they are difficult to parse exactly as intended by the writer/speaker; try writing sentences of just 1 clause to explain what you need.

Comment: Heh, not anything business related. This application is just so old and so much bounded to console system that there is no point in converting it to UI since I just need one form to display.

Comment: If you need one form to display, then by definition it is no longer a console app. You may still attach a standard input and output and such, but it loses **console** app status by opening a Windows window.

Comment: Well I still need the console window for input and output, it still remains my main interface. Is communicating between threads really that hard? It appears to be impossible to ask another thread for a variable or to call a function.

Comment: No; but you do require an appropriate application model. I don't believe you have that yet. Your **console** window may still exist, but the application is no longer a **console app**; you need to reconcile those two facts with your application and threading model.